# Qt QTableView performance 60 fps

Tags: performance, qt, qtableview, qabstracttablemodel

We encountered a problem with the performance of **QTableView**.

**Use case**:

1. The user wants to be able to open up to 10-30 windows with tabular data (we receive data via the Internet)
2. Each table can have from **0 to 13 thousand rows** and about **100 columns** with its own filtering and sorting parameters
3. The data in the table can be updated very often (each of the row can have **100-1000 updates per second**)

**What we have already done:**

1. All data received and processed (sorting/filtering) in separated threads.
2. **QTableView** has limitation of updates with **60 fps**. This is implemented inside the model through the **dataChanged** signal exclusively for the viewport and only for cells what was changed.

**Problem**:
Even after all optimizations in the profiler (Intel VTune) we see the following picture with 20 opened windows:
[image]
As you can see from the graph, more than 70% of the time of the main thread is occupied by rendering the **QTableView (QWidgetPrivate)**.
At the same time, the application responsiveness to user actions significantly decreased.
The test was carried out on the pretty powerful hardware - Intel core i7-12700KF with ssd and 64 Gb RAM.
**Does anyone know how to speed up the rendering of QTableView?** Maybe the only way is a custom view implementation with painting overriding?

Comment: If 60 fps is hard requirement, look for Qt Quick. If that's not a hard requirement, just "pretty smooth" is enough, then you can see what you can do to optimize QTableView. It's possible you will have to implement custom table view optimized just for your use case, if fps perf is a hard requirement.

Comment: Or don't update the model that often but only every 0,5s in a batch instead every time a change comes in.

Comment: It would be useful to have more details about the "60fps limitation" and other aspects like the amount of currently visible cells, usage of custom delegates, etc. Note that when `dataChanged()` is emitted with two different indexes, QAbstractItemView will always update the *whole* viewport, even if only two cells were affected by the change. As mentioned above, reaching a high fps for a similar amount of widgets (tables) and their contents may be difficult: while Qt has good optimizations, it doesn't provide the level of scalability you'd probably need, and you may have to do it on your own.

Comment: "_Or don't update the model that often but only every 0,5s in a batch instead every time a change comes in_" - we do not update model "every time a change comes in". As I wrote in the post rendering limited with 60 fps. Obviously 2 update per second not enough for our requirements.

Comment: "_It would be useful to have more details about the "60fps limitation" and other aspects like the amount of currently visible cells, usage of custom delegates_" - about fps - it is requirement, must be not less than 30; "amount of currently visible cells" depends on user screen, approximately 17 row and 10 columns. Content - just usual text right now without custom delegates.

Comment: Just to clarify, your user interface consists of 10-30 tables each with approx 200 'cells' and all updating at 60fps.  Is that correct?  It's probably none of my business (so feel free to tell me so) but can I ask as to the nature of the data being displayed?  That really doesn't seem like a nice UI.